Corrupt addresses in SSRS 2012
I see this sometimes on my company's SSRS 2012 emailed reports.  I will receive copies of the emails but with these obviously corrupt email addresses.  It hasn't happened for about 2 years but it happened today.  I rebooted the SSRS server and it hasn't happened since, any suggestions on what might cause this?


I figured out that all reports that failed this morning are using an outdated plug-in called Secure Email, which adds features like appending the datetime to the report name, zipping the report, etc.  Appears to be the culprit.
